# Cannot build runnable jar file with ant or eclipse?

Tags: jar

I know this question is common, but actually I do many research for it and it still does not work. Please help me. I use NetBean, Eclipse and Ant script, but it does not. I can use the "run" command of ant but cannot with jar. Thanks in advance. My ant script is below:

```
<project name="Java" default="compile">
<property name="sourcedir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="targetdir" value="${basedir}/classes"/>
<property name="execdir" value="${basedir}/exec"/>
<property name="javadocdir" value="${basedir}/doc"/>
<property name="officialName" value="Pronunciation Application"/>
<property name="version" value="1.0.0.0"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${targetdir}"/>    
    <delete dir="${execdir}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${execdir}"/>
    <copy todir="${targetdir}/data">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}/data" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${targetdir}/lib">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}/lib" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${execdir}/data">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}/data" />
    </copy>     
    <copy todir="${execdir}/lib">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}/lib" />
    </copy>     
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean">     
    <javac srcdir="${sourcedir}" destdir="${targetdir}">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${sourcedir}/lib/jna-3.5.1.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${sourcedir}/lib/platform-3.5.1.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${sourcedir}/lib/vlcj-2.2.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${execdir}/pronunciationApp.jar" basedir="${targetdir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="home/MainClaz"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/jna-3.5.1.jar"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/platform-3.5.1.jar"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/vlcj-2.2.0.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java fork="true" classname="home.MainClaz">
        <classpath>
             <pathelement location="${targetdir}" />
             <pathelement location="${targetdir}/lib/jna-3.5.1.jar" />
             <pathelement location="${targetdir}/lib/platform-3.5.1.jar" />
             <pathelement location="${targetdir}/lib/vlcj-2.2.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="javadoc">
    <javadoc sourcepath="."
        sourcefiles="${sourcedir}"
        destdir="${javadocdir}"
        doctitle="${officialName} ${version} API Documentation"
        author="true"
        version="true"
    />
</target>
</project>
```

My structure of this application is:
+src
 - data
  - Audios
   - *.mp3
  - Videos
   - *.mov
  - Images
   - *.jpg
 - package1
  - *.java
 - package2
  - *.java
 - package3
  - *.java
+lib
 - *.jar

Comment: I don't see any ant script here.

Comment: Sorry guy, I'm struggling with posting my ant script in stackoverflow.

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by "runnable jar"? Does running your application with command `java -jar yourjar.jar` work?

Comment: Follow your suggest, I got the error duplicate name.

Comment: Change the attribute Class-Path into: <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/jna-3.5.1.jar lib/platform-3.5.1.jar lib/vlcj-2.2.0.jar"/> and I got the error URI is not hierrachical.

Comment: At last, I fix it successfully. Just edit the class path attribute in jar task and move the data folder outside the arc folder. Thanks.